# What caused the ethernet mac address to change after an update of my linux system?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mac-address

I recently updated my machine and after a reboot I discovered that my ethernet mac address had changed. The router settings for that machine were no longer implemented as it was viewed as a different machine. This doesn't happen for every update, so I'm wondering which package update could have caused this? And is it possible to ensure that the mac address remains static even if w/e package caused this is updated?

I'm running arch btw

Comment: It is not normal for MAC to change at all.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine, or a physical server?

Comment: Do you run a bridge on the external interface?

Comment: @Gerrit  I have a bridge for my virtual machines, but the mac address which changed is on my physical ethernet. Could this be

Comment: Did the first 6 digits change?  It might help to know the new value of the first 6 digits of the mac address.

Comment: There are many configuration strewn around the internet where bridges are made with the external interface to enable virtual machines to occupy an external address. If you do not set the mac of the bridge, this may fluctuate. `ip link set br0 address 00:0a:e7:2c:44:2a` where the mac must be that of the ethernet interface itself.